# How to generate a output like this?

Tags: python, data-science-model

[image]

can u please give an explanation for this ?

Comment: would be nice if your question includes actual data in text instead of an image so that we can quickly answer it.

Comment: I guess the `shopify_customer_id` in the 2nd and 3rd row of the output dataframe is wrong..

Comment: Please consider reformatting your question as text/markdown to remove pictures so that your problem can be easily reproduced.

Answer (score 2):

Using the example dataframe provided by@JahKnows:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'shopify_customer_id': [1,1,2,3,4,5], 
                        'financial_status': ['paid', 'refunded', 'paid', 'refunded','paid', 'paid'],
                        'count': [8, 1, 13, 1, 1, 1], 
                        'order_amt': [19, 19, 0, 19, 0, 24]})
```

You could also do the following:

```
df=df.groupby(['shopify_customer_id','financial_status']).sum().unstack()
df.columns = ['_'.join(col).strip() for col in df.columns.values]
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df.fillna(0,inplace=True)
```

That gives you this (if this is what you intend to have!):

```
   shopify_customer_id  count_paid  count_refunded  order_amt_paid  order_amt_refunded
0                    1         8.0             1.0            19.0                19.0
1                    2        13.0             0.0             0.0                 0.0
2                    3         0.0             1.0             0.0                19.0
3                    4         1.0             0.0             0.0                 0.0
4                    5         1.0             0.0            24.0                 0.0
```

Answer (score -1):

The dataframe can be defined as follows

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'shopify_customer_id': [1,1,2,3,4,5], 
                        'financial_status': ['paid', 'refunded', 'paid', 'refunded', 'paid', 'paid'],
                        'count': [8, 1, 13, 1, 1, 1], 
                        'order_amt': [19, 19, 0, 19, 0, 24]})
```

This gives the table you described above. Now we will perform the transformation. We will use a dictionary to keep track of all the customers in the database. The first if statement in the code below will add customers not yet in the list. Then we will check if the transaction is a 'sale' or a 'refund'. And we will update the dictionary for the given customer accordingly.

```
shopify_customers = {}
for i in df.iterrows():
    row = i[1]
    if row['shopify_customer_id'] not in shopify_customers:
        shopify_customers.update({row['shopify_customer_id']: 
                                  {'shopify_customer_id': row['shopify_customer_id'],
                                   'order_count_paid': 0,
                                   'order_count_refunded': 0,
                                   'order_amt_paid': 0,
                                   'order_amt_refunded': 0}})

    if row['financial_status'] == 'paid':
        shopify_customers[row['shopify_customer_id']]['order_count_paid'] += row['count']
        shopify_customers[row['shopify_customer_id']]['order_amt_paid'] += row['order_amt']

    elif row['financial_status'] == 'refunded':
        shopify_customers[row['shopify_customer_id']]['order_count_refunded'] += row['count']
        shopify_customers[row['shopify_customer_id']]['order_amt_refunded'] += row['order_amt']
```

Finally we will put the data into a pandas DataFrame

```
pd.DataFrame(data = [shopify_customers[i] for i in shopify_customers])
```

Comment: Looping over the rows is best avoided when possible.